# Any limitation for display connection on macbook pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I'm trying to connect 2 displays to macbook pro with M1, 2021.
I need to use them to extend desktop, not to mirror. For that I have the following adapter, which claims to give dual monitor.
[image]
However, the most I can achieve is mirroring mode, from which I conclude that there is a limitation in usb-c port or macbook video adapter to use single usb-c port per display. It means if I want to have extending mode, I need to use two usb-c ports(which obviously tested and works). Can someone confirm this limitation?

Comment: Could we get a link to the product you've taken a screenshot of?

Comment: @Thinkr https://www.startech.com/en-de/universal-laptop-docking-stations/dk30c2dagpd

Comment: Short answer:  you have to use two separate ports for two separate monitors.